# Is it possible to give a few days delay when using sqs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I need to handle some events in my lambda. When the lambda receive an event, it needs to update the data in database. But the event includes a `date` which is a future date, I need to implement a logic to write to database when at the future `date`.

For example, if today is `2021-08-20`, when I revive this event, I need to write to database 11 days later. I am thinking to put these events in SQS delay queue but it has a maximum of 15 minutes delay time. And it is far less than what I expected ( could be a few weeks or even a few months later).

```
{
   effectDate: "2021-09-01",
   value: xxxx
}
```

another solution is to create a cloudwatch rule in my lambda. The rule will trigger another lambda to write to db. This solution also has a limitation that cloudwatch rule has a maximum 100 rules per region. I may receive thousands of events per day so I can't rely on this solution.

Using dynamodb TTL + streaming may work but the problem is dynamodb TTL doesn't work well for less than 48 hours. It runs TTL scheduler every 48 hours which means I can't schedule an event which get triggered less than 48 hours.

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a step function for this. In Step Functions there is a Wait-State, that allows you to pause execution until a point in time or for a certain period of time. This can be set per execution.

The docs for the wait state can be found here: [Amazon State Language: Wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html)

A wait state that dynamically waits until a point in time determined by the input (expirydate-key) looks like this:

```json
"wait_until" : {
    "Type": "Wait",
    "TimestampPath": "$.expirydate",
    "Next": "NextState"
}
```

You can do the same for a number of seconds:

```json
"wait_until" : {
    "Type": "Wait",
    "SecondsPath": "$.waitForSeconds",
    "Next": "NextState"
}
```

---

The general idea is that you create a step function with a task that extracts the amount of time to wait, the next state is the Wait-state and after the wait state you do whatever processing is necessary.

Comment: Does wait state have a maximum days it can wait? like months, years etc. I can't find it in the quota https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html. I can only see a 1 year idle time. Is it the limit for wait state?

Comment: I think that's it, yes - it's limited by the maximum execution time of a year that a step function can have.

Comment: Does the long delay affect the AWS cost? Basically, I have an email queue which is processed regularly. I need to schedule a Due Date reminder email to this queue at certain time. So, I'm considering this option. But, since the step function will be in the running state for days, does that increase the cost? Or does the wait doesn't matter and cost is based on the number of executions and not the total time?

Comment: With StepFunctions you pay a low fee for the number of state transitions and not the total runtime, shouldn't matter that much: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/

Answer (score 2):

Given the restrictions you seem to have for the solution, you could simply save your events in a database and write your own logic around it.

You could for example trigger a lambda every 5 minutes (using a cloudwatch rule) that handle the events that are needed for the last 5 minutes. You could of course play with the length of this interval, and it's more robust to not handle the events in the triggered lambda, but place them on a queue for another lambda to handle them (parallel if necessary).

It's more work, but you will have more control over what happens when.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your events in DynamoDB and [setup TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html). You would need to also enable [streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html) and have lambda respond to any TTL events. This would include writing them to your target database.

Comment: I have thought about this solution but DynamoDB TTL doesn't work well for less than 48 hours. Sometimes I need to schedule an event one hour later.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Then you need to create a cloudwatch event scheduled rule, and execute a lambda function each 1h to check for dynamodb records that need to be written in your main db. Your sort key can be timestamp.